# Ruby Array - Beginner Learning about Arrays and Methods

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I'm trying to get over a question in a  Ruby tutorial where it is asking the following -

Create a method named new_array. It should take four arguments and return an array with those same arguments. Start by defining the method structure:**

```
def new_array(a,b,c,d)
  # return an array consisting of the arguments here
end
```

Then it provides Specs to reverse engineer the problem.**

```
describe "new_array" do
  it "creates an array of numbers" do
    new_array(1,2,3,4).should eq([1,2,3,4])
  end
  it "creates an array of strings" do
    new_array("a", "b", "c", "d").should eq(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
  end
end

describe "first_and_last" do
  it "creates new array with numbers" do
    first_and_last([1,2,3]).should eq([1,3])
  end
  it "creates new array with strings" do
    first_and_last(["a", "b", "c", "d"]).should eq(["a", "d"])
  end
end
```

You are to find the following from your solution:

- new_array creates an array of numbers
- new_array creates an array of strings

So far I have the following code, but can't seem to put another array within the method new_array so that I can also produce an array of strings.

```
def new_array(a,b,c,d)
  # return an array consisting of the arguments here
  numbers = [1,2,3,4]
  string = ["a","b","c","d"]


end

new_array(1,2,3,4)
new_array("a","b","c","d")
```

How do I take four arguments and return an array with those same argument within the above method structure?

Comment: Could it be that you can't move forward in the tutorial because it is expecting two methods, `new_array` and `first_and_last`? @xdazz's answer surely should work.  Could you provide a link to the tutorial?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for responding. Actually it doesn't matter about the first_and_last method as I havent gotten there. Im just stuck on how to visually represent two arrays within the method. However, you are right xdazz's answer should work. Unfortunately I dont have a good way to share the tutorial.

Comment: Your comment "visually represent two arrays within the method" suggests to me that you aren't looking at this in the right way.  When you pass arguments x, y, z to `new array`, they can be any objects.  Maybe x is a Fixnum, like 3, y is an instance of the class Hash and y is another method.  `new array` does nothing more than create an array, stick these objects in the array (in the same order) and pass the array back to you.  `new array` does not care what those objects are--they're just objects.  So, if you pass all Fixnums, you'll get an array of those Fixnums back, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
def new_array(a,b,c,d)
  [a, b, c, d]
end
```

For unlimited arguments, you could also do:

```
def new_array(*arguments)
  arguments
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However I tried that and it does not satisfy the answer as it wont allow me to move forward in the tutorial. Here is what I have <br/>

Comment: @user1507375 At least it will make your test success. What is the other requirement?

Comment: def new_array(a,b,c,d)
      # return an array consisting of the arguments here
      [1,2,3,4]
      ["a","b","c","d"]

     end

    new_array(1,2,3,4)
    new_array("a","b","c","d")<br/> That is what I have<br/> It satisfied the string element, but I am getting an error<br/>      new_array creates an array of numbers
    RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError

    expected: [1, 2, 3, 4]
         got: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

    (compared using ==)

    exercise_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: If you look at the specs given, it is also looking for a second method called first_and_last and that will be part of the reason his code is not passing.

Answer (score 0):

where you have:

```
def new_array(a,b,c,d)
  # return an array consisting of the arguments here
  numbers = [1,2,3,4]
  string = ["a","b","c","d"]
end
```

your code is accurate, but you did not return anything. try adding one more line that just says `numbers` to return it. like so:

```
def new_array(a, b, c, d)
  # return an array consisting of the arguments here
  numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
end
```

might work, for the purposes of your tutorial. in practice, xdazz's answer is 100% right

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tutorial is expecting two methods: `first_and_last` and `new_array`.

`first_and_last` will always do the same thing, so we'll define that first.

```
def first_and_last(*args)
    [args[0], args[-1]] #returns a new array containing first and last arguments
end
```

For `new_array` you have two options. One that will only take 4 arguments, and one that will take an unlimited number.

```
def new_array(a, b, c, d) #only takes four arguments
    [a, b, c, d] #returns a new array containing those arguments in order given
end

def new_array(*args) #takes unlimited arguments
    args #same thing, but more efficient on typing
end
```

The same goes for `first_and_last` of course, following a similar format. However, this should pass the specs given.

On top of that, it looks like the method you wrote is just a little bit off. Ruby returns the last value returned by any operation in the method, and setting a value also returns that value as `eval` will tell you. For example, the code `x = 3` returns the integer value `3`. So since you defined your `new_array` method to only define a number and string array and the string array was defined second, it will ALWAYS return the value of the string array.